# Replace numbers in string to numbers + "f"

Tags: c#, regex, replace, calculator, dynamic-expresso

I want to make tiny calculator that if you write for example *2/3* and you have got 0.6666667. I use DynamicExpresso.Core library but I need to write *2f/3f* to have 0.6666667 (if I write *2/3* I get 0). I think I should use somethink like `forCounting = Regex.Replace(forCounting, Regex.Match(forCounting, @"\d+").Value, Regex.Match(forCounting, @"\d+").Value + "f");` but it adds f after only first number. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```cs
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"\d+(?:\.\d+)?";
        string substitution = "$0f";
        string input = "Text: 2/3, 1.9";
        string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, substitution);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

See [C# proof](https://tio.run/##ZZBNSwMxEIbv@RXD0sMubuPXyS5SQXrTiwpeeknTsQTSbMhMZEX629dJW/GjcxnC@2TmfcfS1PYJxzGTCxt4/iDGbad@v/QLDqyfcJO9SYshJiRyfaBOqZhX3lmw3hDBYjDb6FF9KpA6SsSGpb33bg2PxoW62asHphRxKquiYcYU4BbuquX6rJ7Pllp6M6@6/yjlFbHjzGJC@Gpy8XYKuRAzF7WYn8HV@XULl/rmFJQ02RdSAuIgMaM3Fuv9//bbVvtnafMz5F7u0HvUr8kxPriA9WHeEdmp3Th@AQ).

**Results**: `Text: 2f/3f, 1.9f`

Answer (score 0):

Starting with DynamicExpresso [2.6.0](https://github.com/davideicardi/DynamicExpresso/releases/tag/v2.6.0), it's possible to set a default numeric type.
For example, you can ask it to consider all numbers as double, and get the result you expect:

```cs
var target = new Interpreter();
target.SetDefaultNumberType(DefaultNumberType.Double);

var dbl = target.Eval<double>("2/3");
Console.WriteLine(dbl); // 0.6666666666666666
```

Answer (score -1):

Good code:

```
forCounting= Regex.Replace(forCounting, @"([0-9.]+)", @"$0f");
```

Comment: This is no good, `([0-9.]+)` also matches `........`. See my update.